# Displaying google map in android app with specified options

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new to android development and I had been trying to display a map in my application for some time now. I finally managed to do it but I want to display it with some specified options such as zoom level, location, etc but its proving difficult.

The following is my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

And the following is my .java file

```
package com.fourapps.cabkonnect;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.graphics.Color;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

/**
 * Created by nanakay on 6/6/13.
 */
public class Home extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;

    private static final LatLng GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE = new LatLng(37.828891,-122.485884);
    private static final LatLng APPLE = new LatLng(37.3325004578, -122.03099823);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (map == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google maps not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

The map is displaying but I would want to display it with my own options. 
I would be very happy if someone could help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First have to obtain the current location:

```
private Location mCurrentLocation;
mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
```

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) to know more.

And then you can animate to the location using:

```
LatLng myLaLn = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLaLn)
                .zoom(15)
                .bearing(45)
                .tilt(70)
                .build();

 CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);

 map.animateCamera(camUpd3);
```

I give you a simple but complete example to show a map and the current location:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
        // map.
        if (map == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (map == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google maps not available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Waiting for location",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getApplicationContext(), this, // ConnectionCallbacks
                    this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mLocationClient != null) {
            mLocationClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client
     * finishes successfully. At this point, you can request the current
     * location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            centerInLoc();
        }
    }

    private void centerInLoc() {
        LatLng myLaLn = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
                mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLaLn)
                .zoom(15).bearing(45).tilt(70).build();

        CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);
        map.animateCamera(camUpd3);

        MarkerOptions markerOpts = new MarkerOptions().position(myLaLn).title(
                "my Location");
        map.addMarker(markerOpts);
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the location client
     * drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error
         * has a resolution, try sending an Intent to start a Google Play
         * services activity that can resolve error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available
             */
            Log.e("Home", Integer.toString(connectionResult.getErrorCode()));
        }
    }
}
```

Note1: I omitted the "Check for Google Play Services" part by simplicity but it should be added as a good practice.

Note2: You need the [google-play-services_lib](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install) project and reference it from yours.

You can find all information about interacting with google maps in android [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity)

From the google maps documentation referenced above, just some examples:

Zoom controls:

*The Maps API provides built-in zoom controls that appear in the bottom right hand corner of the map. These are enabled by default, but can be disabled by calling* `UiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(boolean)`.

My Location button:

*The My Location button appears in the top right corner of the screen only when the My Location layer is enabled. When a user clicks the button, the camera animates to focus on the user's current location if the user's location is currently known. A click will also trigger the GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener. You can disable the button from appearing altogether by calling* `UiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(boolean)`.

Add a marker:

*The below example demonstrates how to add a marker to a map. The marker is created at coordinates 0,0, and displays the string "Hello world" in an infowindow when clicked.*

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Hello world"));
```

Comment: I get what you mean, but I don't want the user to click a certain button before the camera animates to his/her current location. What I want is for the map to automatically detect the current location of the user and display that at a certain zoom level right when it is displayed. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer in order to be more accurate. The key is you have to get the current location first using the location APIs: 
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: I followed through the link that you gave me earlier and I was trying to do a similar thing. But it kept giving me an error even when I had declared and initialized mLocation Client. So again, in the code you gave above, how did you initialize the mLocationClient and what object or class did you use to declare the myLoc variable? Sorry for bothering you but I really appreciate your help so far. Thanks

Comment: I added a complete example to clear up your doubts. You can find the full project here: https://github.com/josuadas/LocationDemo I hope it´s useful to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @josuads, you've been a real saviour. Its just unfortunate I don't have enough points to vote you up, I would have done exactly that. But it seems to me that using LocationClient.getLastLocation is not as accurate as using lets say map.getMyLocation. Any ideas?

Comment: You´re welcome @ChristianKacob. But I don´t agree with your last assertion. I tried both location strategies and I got better performance with the Google Location Services API. 

And not only me ;) See: "The strategies described in this guide apply to the platform location API in android.location. With the Google Location Services API, part of Google Play Services [...] you'll get better battery performance, as well as more appropriate accuracy, by using the Location Services API" from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: In the specific example of getMyLocation, from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getMyLocation() : 

_This method is deprecated.
use com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient instead. LocationClient provides improved location finding and power usage_ Meta-Note: You can´t upvote but you can mark an answer as correct because you are the questioner - just FYI, of course you can wait for a better answer ;)